# How do I use Windows Phone Device Manager?

Tags: 7.5, wpdm

First off, I am not sure whether this belongs in superuser or here, so I just put it here.

I have no idea how to use [Windows Phone Device Manager](http://www.touchxperience.com/windows-phone-device-manager/) (WPDM).  It's "advertised" as freeware, but, when I actually go to use it, it appears that you have to pay for it.  When I execute WPDM with my WP7.5 HTC Trophy, I get this message:

*Support not available to unregistered users* 
[image]

Okay, fine.  I don't get support for free.  I consider myself an intermediate-to-advanced user, so I can handle that.  However, when I attempt to use the File Explorer, I get this message:

*Your phone must be registered or unlocked in order to use Windows Phone Device Manager* 
[image]

Well, my phone *is* unlocked (ie, I entered my pin to get past the lock screen).  What do I have to do to actually be able to use this application?

Comment: This is probably off topic, but I assume it means that your phone is not developer unlocked.

Comment: @row1 So, to use this app, I have to pay Microsoft a subscription fee too unlock my phone?  What about registering my phone?  What's the difference between registering and unlocking in the context that these terms are used in the second error message?

Comment: I know nothing about this application, but some apps like this require your phone to be developer unlocked so that you can run custom software. This might help http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/can-you-explain-unlock-jailbreak-custom-rom-etc-and-how-to-do-it

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? You are having problem with this software but you didn't explain why you need it? You want to load side-loaded apps or you need to unlock for use it in another carrier (my guesses)?

Comment: You can developer unlock up to 3 phones at a time, for LIFE, for $19. You also get to developer unlock your Windows PCs (Windows 8 and up).

Answer (score 1):

After reading the requirements on the program's website, I believe this is because you need to have the phone developer unlocked before using applications that access IsolatedStorage. The fact that it mentions you need the 7.1 SDK installed is enough for me.

[You can now get a combined Windows Phone and Windows developer account, for life, for only $19.](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted#3) See #2 below to learn what dev unlocking your phone does.

Be aware that as of 12/31/2014, Windows Phone 7.5 devices can no longer be developer unlocked. However, if your device was dev unlocked recently, it will still work for one year after you unlocked it (basically, the latest dev unlocked 7.5 will run out by the end of 2015).

If you didn't dev unlock your device by 12/31/2014, you're out of luck. To help explain the different types of "unlocking" here is a basic rundown:

1. **PIN unlock** - just means your phone is user locked. To unlock a PIN locked phone, side up the lock screen and enter your PIN. This
   lasts until the lockscreen timeout is reached
2. **Developer Unlock** - This unlocks the device to allow external programs to access IsolatedStorage, LocalStorage and deploy unsigned
   applications from Visual Studio or sideloading. To dev unlock a
   phone, use the tool that comes with the WP SDK. You sign in with the
   same Microsoft Account you use for your DevAccount. It's as simple
   as signing into Outlook. DevUnlocked devices stay unlocked for one
   year or until the dev removes that device from their account. Most
   common dev accounts allow for up to 3 unlocked devices at a time
   (which can be changed at any time) and up to 10 unsigned
   applications installed at a time.
3. **Carrier Unlock** - When you put a another carrier's SIM card into a phone that is locked to another carrier, you will be asked to
   enter a code (for example, you have an ATT 920 and try to use a
   TMobile SIM card) This code usually takes the form of long PIN
   number that you enter into the phone to allow the other carrier's
   SIM to work. Carrier Unlocking is permanent.
4. **Interop Unlock** (aka OEM unlock) - An OEM unlocked device is an extremely high level unlock, allowing the developers to access
   core OS services and low-hardware level services. This level unlock
   is reserved for companies like Nokia, HTC, Skype, etc. [You can
   register for OEM access](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/oem/), but without a valid reason, you'll be
   quickly denied.

I highly recommend getting a regular Developer Account, it is for life and only $19. You can side-load apps and use other 3rd party software like the [WP Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score -1):

When the Windows Phone Device Manager says...

> {NAME} is not registered. Your phone must be registered or unlocked in order to use > Windows Phone Device Manager.

...it means that your phone needs to be **carrier unlocked** (not keypad unlocked).

[This article explains well what it means to have a carrier unlocked phone.](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1035_3-57598544-94/confused-about-locked-vs-unlocked-phones-ask-maggie-explains/)

Comment: Probably needs to be interop unlocked...